# How to Add Dynamic Column to GridView

Tags: asp.net

I want to add dynamic columns and datatype to gridview in ASP.Net, so I can assign datasource as a data table

Comment: What have you tired yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the columns to the `DataTable`, populate your data and then assign the `DataTable` to the DataSource of the gridview.

```
DataTable workTable = new DataTable("Customers");

DataColumn workCol = workTable.Columns.Add("CustID", typeof(Int32));
workCol.AllowDBNull = false;
workCol.Unique = true;

workTable.Columns.Add("CustLName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("CustFName", typeof(String));
workTable.Columns.Add("Purchases", typeof(Double));
```

Refer: [Adding Columns to a DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hfx3s9wd%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)